# Check for empty inline struct

Tags: go

Can an inline struct in Go be checked for emptiness?

The following example checks `p`, which is of type `Person` for emptiness.

It also defines the inline struct `i`. (How) can `i` be checked for emptiness?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Person struct {
    name string
}

func main() {
    // Types can be checked for emptiness.
    p := Person{}
    if (p == Person{}) {
        fmt.Println("Empty!")
    }

    // But: how to check for an empty inline struct?
    // I.e. how to check, if i is empty?
    var i struct {
        value int
    }
    fmt.Println(i) // Required, or compiler will complain about unused 'i'.
}
```

Comment: The equivalent would be `if i == struct{value int}{}`.

Comment: This is why anonymous structs are rarely used, they're very unwieldy if you need to do much of anything with them. Just create a named type.

Comment: Can you use `reflect`? [`Value.IsZero`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Value.IsZero)